# Can't get rubaxa:sortable to work

Tags: meteor, rubaxa-sortable

tasks is from an api call. The list is showing up but no dragging is happening. The tasks are all showing up as one block div#object.sortable.target when i hover using javascript console.

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="list-pair col-sm-12">


          {{#each tasks}}

       <div class="sortable target" id="object"> 
       {{#sortable items=tasks animation="100" ghostClass="sortable-ghost" }}


            <!--<div class="list-group-item"> -->


                {{title}}


        {{/sortable}}
</div>
           <!-- </div> -->
            {{else}}
            <p>List is empty.</p>


{{/each}}


</div></div>
```

server code:

```
Sortable.collections = ['tasks'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use {{#each}} when you use {{#sortable}}